# How to give button label using Thymeleaf from i18n

Tags: java, html, spring-boot, internationalization, thymeleaf

Currently I am trying to replace the word `Save` from button label with a value from *message_en.properties* file.

```
<input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary btn-block"/>
```

I have tried as below:

```
<input type="submit" th:text="#{newuser.page.saveBtn}" class="btn btn-primary btn-block"/>
```

But it's not giving the result I expected. Please help me out to solve the issue.

Comment: have you configure messageSource ?

Comment: Yes, everything is working well, except label on the save button

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Shouldn't it be like this?

```
<input type="submit"
    th:value="#{newuser.page.saveBtn}"
    class="btn btn-primary btn-block"/>
```

Comment: It is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you it is working now

Answer (score 3):

you can use button, it's working for me

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" th:text="#{newuser.page.saveBtn}"></button>
```

Comment: Yes this works fine, but I have asked this question because there are so many other html files which use `<input type="submit" value="***" class="btn btn-primary btn-block"/>`. And I am wondering is there a way to use thymeleaf here without changing much of code. Anyway, thank you for answering